# Update Query with Aggregate, Join and Date Range Conditions (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, aggregate

I am having a very hard time with an UPDATE query with aggregates and cannot find this question answered. I tried seemingly every permutation of 
UPDATE, but cannot get it to work. Should be simple, though.

Two Tables:

### Employees

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦═════════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ PersonID ║  Name ║  RangeBeginDate ║  RangeEndDate ║  HoursSched ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬═════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║        1 ║ Joe   ║ 3/18/2012       ║ 3/17/2013     ║ NULL        ║
║        1 ║ Joe   ║ 3/18/2013       ║ 3/17/2014     ║ NULL        ║
║        1 ║ Joe   ║ 3/18/2014       ║ 3/17/2015     ║ NULL        ║
║        2 ║ Bill  ║ 3/18/2012       ║ 3/17/2013     ║ NULL        ║
║        2 ║ Bill  ║ 3/18/2013       ║ 3/17/2014     ║ NULL        ║
║        2 ║ Bill  ║ 3/18/2014       ║ 1/10/2015     ║ NULL        ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩═════════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

### Schedule

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ PersonID ║ SchedDate ║ SchedHours ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ 3/21/2013 ║          8 ║
║        1 ║ 3/22/2013 ║          6 ║
║        1 ║ 3/23/2013 ║          9 ║
║        1 ║ 5/15/2014 ║          8 ║
║        1 ║ 6/15/2014 ║          9 ║
║        1 ║ 1/22/2015 ║          3 ║
║        2 ║ 3/29/2012 ║          8 ║
║        2 ║ 4/1/2012  ║          9 ║
║        2 ║ 5/9/2014  ║          6 ║
║        2 ║ 5/10/2014 ║          9 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

I'm trying to UPDATE the temporary Employees table for the total scheduled hours for each employee where the SchedDate in the Schedule table is greater than or equal to the RangeBeginDate and less than or equal to the RangeEndDate in the Employees table. The result should look like:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦═════════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ PersonID ║  Name ║  RangeBeginDate ║  RangeEndDate ║  HoursSched ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬═════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║        1 ║ Joe   ║ 3/18/2012       ║ 3/17/2013     ║           0 ║
║        1 ║ Joe   ║ 3/18/2013       ║ 3/17/2014     ║          23 ║
║        1 ║ Joe   ║ 3/18/2014       ║ 3/17/2015     ║          20 ║
║        2 ║ Bill  ║ 3/18/2012       ║ 3/17/2013     ║          17 ║
║        2 ║ Bill  ║ 3/18/2013       ║ 3/17/2014     ║           0 ║
║        2 ║ Bill  ║ 3/18/2014       ║ 1/10/2015     ║          15 ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩═════════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

It would be easy if it were just getting a sum of the schedule for each PersonID, but to get a SUM of a subgroup based on a WHERE clause that compares dates is difficult (for me). I either get errors, or the PersonID grand total in every column or just a partial fill of one row for each PersonID filled in.

Here's one of many that gave me errors:

```
SELECT T.PersonID, Name, SubQuery.SchedSum
  FROM #Employees AS E
       INNER JOIN
    (SELECT PersonID, SUM(scheduledhours) AS SchedSum
       FROM #Schedule S
      GROUP BY PersonID)
    AS SubQuery
    SubQuery.PersonID = T.PersonID
      WHERE S.SchedDate >= E.RangeBeginDate
        AND S.SchedDate <= E.RangeEndDate
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Even though it's SQL Server, I'd prefer to make the code compatible with MySQL if possible. Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you describe the problem, this is a `join` with a `group by`.  However, the `join` needs to take into account both the person and the dates:

```
SELECT e.PersonID, e.Name, SUM(s.SchedSum)
FROM #Employees E LEFT JOIN
     #Schedule s
     ON s.PersonId = e.PersonId and
        s.SchedDate BETWEEN e.RangeBeginDate and e.RangeEndDate
GROUP BY e.PersonID, e.Name, e.RangeBeginDate, e.RangeEndDate;
```

You can readily turn this into an `update` by joining to the results:

```
UPDATE e
    SET HoursSched = ssum
    FROM #Employees e JOIN
         (SELECT e.PersonID, e.RangeBeginDate, e.RangeEndDate, SUM(s.SchedSum) as ssum
          FROM #Employees E LEFT JOIN
               #Schedule s
               ON s.PersonId = e.PersonId and
                  s.SchedDate BETWEEN e.RangeBeginDate and e.RangeEndDate
          GROUP BY e.PersonID, e.RangeBeginDate, e.RangeEndDate
         ) ee
         ON ee.PersonId = e.PersonId and
            ee.RangeBeginDate = e.RangeBeginDate and
            ee.RangeEndDate = e.RangeEndDate;
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you. The first SELECT query returned only each employee total for all date ranges. Maybe that is what you intended with that query.  The second UPDATE query had errors, "No column name was specified for column 4 of 'ee'   and 'The correlation name 'ee' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause'.  I've tried to edit it, but with no luck.

Comment: @Mark . . . When I wrote the first query, I thought each row in `#Employee` had a unique id, so I *though* it was one row per row in that table.  That's fixed by including the dates in the `group by`.  The second was just a case of not finishing edits.  Obviously, `sum()` doesn't belong in a `set` statement -- so that was a bad mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
update Employees 
set HoursSched = (select isnull(sum(s.HoursSched ), 0) 
         from Schedule s 
         where s.person_id = t.person_id and s.SchedDate >= t.RangeBeginDate and s.SchedDate <= t.RangeEndDate )
from Employees t
```

Fiddle:

```
declare @t table(person_id int, sd date, ed date, h int)
declare @s table(person_id int, d date, h int)

insert into @t values
(1, '20120318', '20130317', null),
(1, '20130318', '20140317', null),
(1, '20140318', '20150317', null),
(2, '20120318', '20130317', null),
(2, '20130318', '20140317', null),
(2, '20140318', '20150110', null)

insert into @s values
(1, '20130321', 8),
(1, '20130322', 6),
(1, '20130323', 9),
(1, '20140515', 8),
(1, '20140615', 9),
(1, '20150122', 3),
(2, '20120329', 8),
(2, '20120401', 9),
(2, '20140509', 6),
(2, '20140510', 9)


update @t set h = (select isnull(sum(s.h), 0) from @s s where s.person_id = t.person_id and s.d >= t.sd and s.d <= t.ed)
from @t t

select * from @t
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1503

Comment: Fiddle, I used your answer too. Since I'm new, it doesn't let me vote up your answer.